# Multiple instances of the same PHP project using classes from the wrong directory

Tags: php, apache, autoload, fpm, xcache

We have a web server with 4 vhosts of the same project (for different countries).

Our setup is Apache24 with PHP-FPM running 5.6. We use the composer autoloader with our classes directory following the PSR-0 autoloading standard. The composer autoloader is committed to the repository and the `autoload_classmap.php` doesn't contain any paths at all.

**Directory structure**

```
/var/www/website.co.uk
/var/www/website.co.nz
/var/www/website.ca
...
```

**Project structure**

```
public_html/
--/controls
--/classes
--index.php
```

When we serve files from any of the hosts, it will always use **classes** from the `website.co.nz` folder however when we call any other file such as a "control" it is served from the correct path.

We have already disabled Zend Opcache, however Xcache is still enabled. I can't find any reasonable documentation for Xcache which will tell me whether or not I can disable it.

The `website.co.nz` was deployed first, I'm unsure of this is of any value but worth mentioning.

**Classmap file:**

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
);
```

Comment: do you have separate vendor folders for each project?

Comment: there is a vendor directory within each of the sites folders. However composer dump-autoload isn't run on the server, it is run before we commit files to the repository. However, this shouldn't matter as this is done on our local systems, which doesn't have a similar path to the one being served

Comment: how is the vendor folder deployed? installed on a non-prod server, and copied over? if so you should get the autoload files. if still no, check each projects require_once for the autoload and make sure they aren't pointoing to the same one

Comment: They use relative paths in the require_once, and it's not done on a non-prod or clone-setup server, it's just generated locally, where the actual path will be completely different to any of the hosts on the prod server

Comment: if it's generated locally, i take it the autoload classmap file is populated? do you then copy this to prod etc?

Comment: The classmap file doesn't have any classes in the last, and yes it is copied in its "blank" form